# Как назначить обычного бота админом в телеграм-канале, используя юзер-бота на pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Нужно назначить обычного бота админом в телеграм-каналах, используя юзер-бота на `pyrogram`.

Пробовал метод `promote_chat_member()`, но для него требуется, чтобы бот был участником канала, а для бота так не сделаешь.

Answer (score 0):

Ссылка на нужный метод в доках

https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/promote_chat_member#pyrogram.Client.promote_chat_member

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).